# Cmake собрать проект c++ в windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, сборка

Есть исходный код на [c++](https://github.com/psychocrypt/xmr-stak-cpu)
Пытаюсь собрать его в Cmake в проект для запуска в VS.
Файл CMakeLists.txt имеет такой вид:

```
    PROJECT (miner)  
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
    ADD_SUBDIRECTORY (src)
```

Файл расположен в корневой папке. 
В директории  src — код
В директории bi - должен быть билд проекта

Скриншот Cmake: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Лог Cmake](https://pastebin.com/yMTEDNDx)  (со скриншота)

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (PROJECT):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    C:/Program Files/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    Microsoft (R) Build Engine ўҐабЁЁ 14.0.25123.0

    (C) Љ®аЇ®а жЁп Њ ©Єа®б®дв (Microsoft Corporation). ‚бҐ Їа ў  § йЁйҐл.



    ‘Ў®аЄ   з в  27.07.17 1:22:59.

    Џа®ҐЄв "\\mac\Home\Desktop\cmake222\bi\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" ў г§«Ґ 1 (жҐ«ҐўлҐ ®ЎкҐЄвл Ї® г¬®«з Ёо).

    C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [\\mac\Home\Desktop\cmake222\bi\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]

    ‘Ў®аЄ  Їа®ҐЄв  "\\mac\Home\Desktop\cmake222\bi\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" § ўҐаиҐ  (жҐ«ҐўлҐ ®ЎкҐЄвл Ї® г¬®«з Ёо) б ®иЁЎЄ®©.



    ЋиЁЎЄ  бЎ®аЄЁ.



    "\\mac\Home\Desktop\cmake222\bi\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (жҐ«Ґў®© ®ЎкҐЄв Ї® г¬®«з Ёо) (1) ->

    (–Ґ«Ґў®© ®ЎкҐЄв Desktop_PlatformPrepareForBuild) -> 

      C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [\\mac\Home\Desktop\cmake222\bi\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]



        ЏаҐ¤гЇаҐ¦¤ҐЁ©: 0

        ЋиЁЎ®Є: 1



    ‡ ва зҐ®Ґ ўаҐ¬п: 00:00:00.17



  Exit code: 1



Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "//mac/Home/Desktop/cmake222/bi/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Запускаю все это на OS X под Parallels (Win 7)
К сожалению, версия Cmake под OS X не позволяет собирать проекты под VS.

Comment: У Вас какие-то проблемы с Visual Studio и SDK, сначала убедитесь, что всё работает с проектом самой студии, который она создаёт. Потом переходите на CMake. И ещё: `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY` должна указывать на директорию, в которой находится CMake-файл, Вы это понимаете?

Comment: > The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found.

Answer (score 2):

После установки Win SDK все заработало. Всем спасибо!